# How to stop iTunes from warning me about sync-ing notes

Tags: iphone

When I sync my iPhone with my iMac (via iTunes, which is obvious, iGuess) I often get a warning message that I've changed more than 5% of my notes.  This would be fine if it did not stop the sync from proceeding.  But it does, so it's not fine.  All I can find in the docs is how to address this via iSync, nothing about iTunes.  (When I try to start iSync, I get iTunes.)  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: can the tag change from lotus-notes to just notes... since it's not about lotus-notes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to start iSync via Spotlight.  Accessing the iSync->Preferences menu item gives me the following window:

[image: iSync Preferences]

Try unchecking that item and resyncing.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to disable that warning in iTunes for Windows:

1. Edit->Preferences
2. Devices tab
3. Uncheck "Warn when [more than 5%   v] of the data on this computer will be changed
4. Click OK
5. Resync

[image: Devices Tab in Settings]

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X.  I cannot find that check box in the Devices section (or any section) of the iTunes Preferences dialog.  Excellent answer for Windows though (+1), and a fine edition to the now-growing knowledge base.

Comment: Hm, ok, sorry about that, didn't notice the Mac reference there. You have of course updated to latest iTunes version? Not that I know if this will matter though.

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS X, you need to open iSync, then open its preferences. Uncheck the 'Show Data Change Alert' checkbox.

[image: Location of 'Show Data Change Alert' checkbox]

Comment: But isync doesn't exist anymore on OS X.

Comment: I apologise for being unable to see into the future. Obviously I should I have anticipated iSync being discontinued when I wrote this answer in 2009.